# interfacing keypad with arduino using I2C

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c

I am connecting 4*4 keypad with I2C and then I2C to my arduino uno. But the serial monitor does not display anything when I press a key from keypad. 
This is my code:-

```
#include <Keypad_I2C.h>
#include <Keypad.h>        // GDY120705
#include <Wire.h>

#define I2CADDR 0x27

const byte ROWS = 4; //four rows
const byte COLS = 4; //four columns
//define the symbols on the buttons of the keypads
char hexaKeys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1','2','3','A'},
  {'4','5','6','B'},
  {'7','8','9','C'},
  {'*','0','#','D'}
};
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {0, 1, 2, 3}; //connect to the row pinouts of the keypad
byte colPins[COLS] = {4, 5, 6, 7}; //connect to the column pinouts of the

//initialize an instance of class NewKeypad
Keypad_I2C customKeypad( makeKeymap(hexaKeys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS, I2CADDR); 

void setup(){
//  Wire.begin( );
  customKeypad.begin( );        // GDY120705
  Serial.begin(9600);
  }

void loop(){
  Serial.print("Key pressed= ");
  char customKey = customKeypad.getKey();

  if (customKey != NO_KEY){
     Serial.println(customKey);
  }
}
```

This is the simple code for displaying the key pressed.

Connections are:-
R1,R1,R3,R4 is connected to pin no. 4(P0),5(P1),6(P2),7(P3) of I2C. C1,C2,C3,C4 is connected to pin no. 9(P4),10(P5),11(P6),12(P7) of I2C. Pin no. 8(VSS),1(A0), 3(A2) of I2C is connected to ground. Pin no. 2(A1),16(VCC) of I2C is connected to 5V. Pin no. 14(SCL),15(SDA) of I2C is connected to SCL and SDA of I2C. SDA & SCL of I2C is connected to A4,A5 of arduino uno. 
PLEASE HELP!!!

Comment: I2C clock and data lines need to be pulled high. Do you have pull-up resistors? Also, are you sure your address setting is correct?

Comment: yes. address is correct

Comment: where do i need to connect the pull up resistors?

Comment: SCL and SDA. They need to be pulled high.

Comment: i tried this but nothing happened

Comment: can you tell me any other solution to this?

Comment: Are you playing around with this example? https://github.com/joeyoung/arduino_keypads/blob/master/Keypad_I2C/examples/CustomKeypad_I2C/CustomKeypad_I2C.ino If so, looks like there is another optional parameter you can pass to the constructor. Look at the constructor definition in Keypad_I2C.h. The default of for "width" is 1. Depending on the model of your keypad, you may need to set it to something else.